# Adding a text file with a button (in Delphi)

Tags: delphi

i'm in Gr.11 and currently busy with a big project for my IT class.

Basically what I want to do is this.
I want a user to be able to add new text files via a button in my Delphi program itself. So if they press the 'Add' button in the program then a window would pop up with which the user would be able to select the specific text file wherever it may be stored. I'm then going to use that text file and display it.

I've done some research and it seems that using an openDialog component would be the best choice but I wasn't able to figure out how exactly to do this. 
I was also wondering if I'm going to use openDialog if there would be a way to save the text file added somewhere in the main delphi folder so that it wouldn't have to be added each time.

Sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question but I'm still learning Delphi.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) please familiarize yourself with how to ask a good question :) Please provide us a code you've tried so far, and wrong behavior of your code :)

Comment: You can use a TOpenDialog to open a file that already exists on disk.  If you're wanting to save a new file, you can use the TSaveDialog.  Btw, what OS and Delphi version?

Comment: You already know which component to use. What's stopping you? And *if there would be a way to save the text file added somewhere in the main delphi folder so that it wouldn't have to be added each time* makes little sense. I suggest you think a bit more about how this will work.

Comment: The [documentation example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/UsingDialogs_(Delphi)) wasn't enough for you? It clearly demonstrates how to use the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

When presenting a dialog to the user in which they can select Files then yes `TOpenDialog` is the common way.

If you want to allow only selecting specific File types then you need to modify the `Filter` for the `TOpenDialog` component.

A simple example of displaying the Open Dialog and loading the selected text file into a `TMemo` would be:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

If you need to open the Text Files silently then don't even use the `TOpenDialog` component.

To save you can use `Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('C:\Some Path\MyFile.txt');` and if you need to present the Save Dialog to the user then use the `TSaveDialog` component and use something like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

The `Filter` can be used the same way for the `TSaveDialog` as the `TOpenDialog` to allow only saving with a specific File Extension.

Answer (score -1):

The all programmatic way: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TOpenDialog

Most of the settings can be set by dropping the TOpenDialog component to the form and setting the properties, then use the Execute method and check for it's result.